# accessing children by key attribute

Tags: python, xml.etree

Using `xml.etree` I need to access an element by a key identifier.

Having as an example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Models>
    <Model Id="1" Name="booname" Description="boo" Filter="b">
        <ModelVariables>
            <Variable Id="1" Token="tothh"  />
            <Variable Id="2" Token="avgtt"  />
        </ModelVariables>
        <Terms>
            <Term Id="1" Description="ln1"  Coefficient="0.24160834" />
            <Term Id="2" Description="ln2"  Coefficient="-0.09360441" />
        </Terms>
    </Model>
    <Model Id="2" Name="fooname" Description="foo" Filter="f">
        <Terms>
            <Term Id="1" Description="e1"  Coefficient="0.36310718" />
            <Term Id="2" Description="e2"  Coefficient="-0.24160834" />
        </Terms>
    </Model>
</Models>
```

How can i access the elements according to the id value? If the argument 2 is passed, whats the most direct way to access all the attributes for model `fooname`?

I've tried to use `findtext`, `find`, and `get` methods with a variation of arguments but i cant access the desired element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` [supports a limited XPath language functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support), but this is enough to get an element by a specific value of an attribute:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Models>
    <Model Id="1" Name="booname" Description="boo" Filter="b">
        <ModelVariables>
            <Variable Id="1" Token="tothh"  />
            <Variable Id="2" Token="avgtt"  />
        </ModelVariables>
        <Terms>
            <Term Id="1" Description="ln1"  Coefficient="0.24160834" />
            <Term Id="2" Description="ln2"  Coefficient="-0.09360441" />
        </Terms>
    </Model>
    <Model Id="2" Name="fooname" Description="foo" Filter="f">
        <Terms>
            <Term Id="1" Description="e1"  Coefficient="0.36310718" />
            <Term Id="2" Description="e2"  Coefficient="-0.24160834" />
        </Terms>
    </Model>
</Models>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

id_value = "2"
model = root.findall(".//Model[@Id='%s']" % id_value)[0]
print(model.attrib)
```

It prints:

```
{'Id': '2', 'Name': 'fooname', 'Description': 'foo', 'Filter': 'f'}
```

Note the use of `.attrib` to access the element attributes.